# How to refresh Image Data in GridView

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-gridview

My App has a Fragment which shows images from a folder in GridView.

On the gridview Item OnClick, I pass filepath,filename & position through Intent to another Activity.

This Activity displays Image in full size...
I used a Delete option to delete the Image from the SdCard and then the finish() is called to exit activity...
The image is deleted but the Gridview isn't refreshed...
It still shows the Thumbnail!

How to Refresh the Gridview when calling finish();?

Fragment which shows Gridview -

```
public class Downloaded extends Fragment{



    // Declare variables
    private String[] FilePathStrings;
    private String[] FileNameStrings;
    private File[] listFile;
    GridView grid;
    GridViewAdapter adapter;
    File file;
   TextView empty;

@Override
public void onActivityCreated( Bundle
savedInstanceState) {
super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    getActivity().setTitle("Saved");
}

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        //Inflating the Layout 
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.gridview_main, container, false); 


        // Check for SD Card
        if (!Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(
                Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Error! No SDCARD Found!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();
        } else {
            // Locate the image folder in your SD Card
            file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                    + File.separator + "Sample");
            // Create a new folder if no folder named SDImageTutorial exist
            file.mkdirs();
        }

        if (file.isDirectory()) {
            listFile = file.listFiles();
            // Create a String array for FilePathStrings
            FilePathStrings = new String[listFile.length];
            // Create a String array for FileNameStrings
            FileNameStrings = new String[listFile.length];

            for (int i = 0; i < listFile.length; i++) {
                // Get the path of the image file
                FilePathStrings[i] = listFile[i].getAbsolutePath();
                // Get the name image file
                FileNameStrings[i] = listFile[i].getName();
            }
        }


        // Locate the GridView in gridview_main.xml
        grid = (GridView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.gridview);

       empty = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.empty);

       empty.setText("You haven't saved any Pic yet...!");

       grid.setEmptyView(empty);

        // Pass String arrays to LazyAdapter Class
        adapter = new GridViewAdapter(getActivity(), FilePathStrings, FileNameStrings);

        // Set the LazyAdapter to the GridView
        grid.setAdapter(adapter);



        // Capture gridview item click
        grid.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {

                Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), ViewImage.class);
                // Pass String arrays FilePathStrings
                i.putExtra("filepath", FilePathStrings);
                // Pass String arrays FileNameStrings
                i.putExtra("filename", FileNameStrings);
                // Pass click position
                i.putExtra("position", position);
                startActivity(i);
            }

        });
        return rootView;
    }
}
```

& here's the ViewImage class which deletes the image -

```
public class ViewImage extends AppCompatActivity {
    // Declare Variable
    TextView text;
    public String[] filepath;
    public int position;
    public String[] filename;

   private TouchImageView imageview;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Get the view from view_image.xml
        setContentView(R.layout.img_act);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);

        // Retrieve data from MainActivity on GridView item click
        Intent i = getIntent();

        // Get the position
        position = i.getExtras().getInt("position");

        // Get String arrays FilePathStrings
          filepath = i.getStringArrayExtra("filepath");

        // Get String arrays FileNameStrings
        filename = i.getStringArrayExtra("filename");

        // Locate the TextView in view_image.xml
        //text = (TextView) //findViewById(R.id.imagetext);

        // Load the text into the TextView followed by the position
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(filename[position]);

        // Locate the ImageView in view_image.xml
        imageview = (TouchImageView) findViewById(R.id.full_image_view);

    // Decode the filepath with BitmapFactory followed by the position
        Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filepath[position]);

        // Set the decoded bitmap into ImageView
        imageview.setImageBitmap(bmp);

@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.image_view, menu);
        return true;
    }


public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) 
    {
        switch (item.getItemId()){

          case R.id.vi;

              File f = new File(filepath[position]);

            if (f.exists())
            {
                f.delete ();
            }
            this.finish();

           break;

            case android.R.id.home:
                onBackPressed();
                break;
                }

        return true;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` in fragment at `onActivityResult` after delete and finish activity.

in your fragment

```
grid.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {

                Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), ViewImage.class);
                // Pass String arrays FilePathStrings
                i.putExtra("filepath", FilePathStrings);
                // Pass String arrays FileNameStrings
                i.putExtra("filename", FileNameStrings);
                // Pass click position
                i.putExtra("position", position);
                startActivityForResult (i, 101);
            }

        });
```

in ViewImage Activity 
onDelete Click write like below

```
case R.id.vi;

              File f = new File(filepath[position]);

            if (f.exists())
            {
                f.delete ();
            }
            Intent i = new Intent();
        i.putInt("POS", your_deleted_item_pos");
        setResult(RESULT_OK, i);
        finish();

           break;
```

and in fragment

```
    @Override
        public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                switch (requestCode) {
                    case 101:
                        if(data.containsKey("POS"){
                         int pos = data.getInt("POS");
                         /*here you have to  Remove item from FilePathStrings and FileNameStrings for particular position.*/
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();  // it only done when your deleted image is remove from list which you bind in gridview.
                        break;

                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: in my case when I call finish(), I should use onActivityResult without that request code, result code & intent data right? and what is that RESULT_OK?

Comment: what an issue now?

Comment: its not refreshing gridview

Comment: have you got a callback in fragment after finish activity?

Comment: i passed d result intent and got back the data i.e. position in the fragment but it still showed the thumbnail.. can we do notifyDataSetChanged in onResume()?